# VueJS - is it possible to disable animation for a specific element under a transition group

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a table that shows rows dynamically based on the amount of items in a list. When an item is added to the list, the table row is animated (with a green background) to show a new row is being added, when I remove an item from the list, the table row is animated (with a red background) to show it is being deleted. I show a row with a message of `There are no more items in the list` when there are no more items.

My problem is when there are **no more items left in the list**, the table row that shows when the list is empty, is animated with the green background I mentioned above, and same when an item is added to the list (from being empty), that row is animated with a red background

**My question:** Is it possible to ignore animating a single element under a `<transition-group>`?

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="item-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody name="fade" is="transition-group">
        <tr v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.id">
            <td>
                {{ item.name }}
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="removeItem(index, item.id)"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr v-if="items.length == 0" class="text-center" key="noItems">
            <td colspan="2">There are no more items in the list</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fade-enter-active {
    transition: opacity 1.5s;
    background-color: #a1ec8e !important;
}

.fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 1.5s;
    background-color: tomato !important;
}

.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0
}
```

**JS:**

```
const App = new Vue({
    el: "#app",

    data() {
        return {
            items: [],
        }
    },

    methods: {
        addItem(item) {
            this.items.push(item);
        },

        removeItem(index) {
            this.items.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove !important from your css. Without it you can overwrite style of rows with something like this:

```
.fade-enter-active[key="noItems"] {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Transition group just adds or remove classes on child elements, but the animation style is controlled solely by the css.